# Is there any tool in informatica like the ombplus in owb to generate the mapping?

Tags: scripting, informatica

In Oracle Warehouse Builder (OWB),we can write a script using OMBPLUS commands and execute that script to create mapping. I heard that there are similar commands in Informatica. I want to know the name of those commands. Please help me in this case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there are no such tools available out-of-the-box. There are few tools available on Marketplace, like:

- https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/infatools_stage_mapping_generator
- https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/stage_mapping_generator